# How to replace whitespaces without the new line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file where each line may end with some fixed TAG surrounded by white spaces, e.g

> some text TAG

I'm writing something like:

```
while (<FILE>) {
  s/\s*TAG\s*$//;
  print;
}
```

The problem is that this remove the new line from the end, is there anyway to tell Perl not to replace the new line? The only thing I thought of is to write

```
s/\s*TAG[ \t]*$//;
```

Is there better way?

[Not sure if this is relevant, but OS is Linux]

thanks.

Comment: It seems that it would be easier just to put the newline back.

Comment: If this will be in a one-liner, adding the `-l` option will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^\S\n]` will match whitespace that's not a newline, so:

```
s/\s*TAG[^\S\n]*$//;
```

Or you could just do:

```
s/\s*TAG\s*$/\n/;
```